# Let $p$ be prime and $a$ be a natural not divisible by $p$. Then, $\exists$ integers $x,y$ such that $ax\equiv y \pmod{p}$ with $0<|x|,|y|<\sqrt{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have proven that a function $f(x,y)=ax-y\pmod{p}$ is not injective. I think that is supposed to help.

Comment: It might help to write a in base sqrt(p), i.e. a = a0 + a1*sqrt(p) with a0, a1 less than sqrt(p), and trying to extract suitable x and y from a0 and a1.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the function $f:[-\lceil\frac{\sqrt{p}}2\rceil, \lceil\frac{\sqrt{p}}2\rceil]^2\to \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z},$ defined by $f(x, y) = a x - y.$ This function is not injective by the pigeonhole principle, so there are two *distinct* pairs $x_1, y_1$ and $x_2, y_2$ which give you the same value. That means that $x=x_1 - x_2, y = y_1 - y_2$ give a solution to your original question, but the upper bound on the absolute value is $2\lceil\frac{\sqrt{p}}2\rceil,$ which is slightly different from the bound you are asked to satisfy.